Is it possible to set "self" context explicitly for type hinting in a random block?
Given some YARD type-hinting context for a class, like
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: items
#
# @!attribute id
#   @return []
# @!attribute description
#   @return [String]
# @!attribute title
#   @return [String]
class Item < ApplicationRecord
end

Is it possible to get title/description type-hinting support by explicitly setting self type-hinting type?
factory :item do
  # ... ?
end

Please note, this question is FactoryBot agnostic.

The following solution seems to work although I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing it.
factory :item do
  # @type [Item]
  self_alias = self

  self_alias. # suggests to autocomplete w/ id/title/description
end


An alternative solution(specific to FactorBot!) might be the following:
# @param model [Item]
factory :item do |model|
  model. # suggests to autocomplete w/ id/title/description
end

